# Partial class definition on C++?

Tags: c++

Anyone knows if is possible to have partial class definition on C++ ?

Something like:

file1.h:

```
  
class Test {
    public:
        int test1();
};
```

file2.h:

```
class Test {
    public:
        int test2();
};
```

For me it seems quite useful for definining multi-platform classes that have common functions between them that are platform-independent because inheritance is a cost to pay that is non-useful for multi-platform classes.

I mean you will never have two multi-platform specialization instances at runtime, only at compile time. Inheritance could be useful to fulfill your public interface needs but after that it won't add anything useful at runtime, just costs.

Also you will have to use an ugly #ifdef to use the class because you can't make an instance from an abstract class:

```
class genericTest {
    public:
        int genericMethod();
};
```

Then let's say for win32:

```
class win32Test: public genericTest {
    public:
        int win32Method();
};
```

And maybe:

```
class macTest: public genericTest {
    public:
        int macMethod();
};
```

Let's think that both win32Method() and macMethod() calls genericMethod(), and you will  have to use the class like this:

```
 #ifdef _WIN32
 genericTest *test = new win32Test();
 #elif MAC
 genericTest *test = new macTest();
 #endif

 test->genericMethod();
```

Now thinking a while the inheritance was only useful for giving them both a genericMethod() that is dependent on the platform-specific one, but you have the cost of calling two constructors because of that. Also you have ugly #ifdef scattered around the code.

That's why I was looking for partial classes. I could at compile-time define the specific  platform dependent partial end, of course that on this silly example I still need an ugly #ifdef inside genericMethod() but there is another ways to avoid that.

Comment: First, non-virtual functions don't incur "costs" and second, if your code doesn't indicate which version of the interface you're using, working on one version will break the other version, e.g. when you do test->win32Method().  Platform specific classes are not the same and deserve diferent names.

Comment: And you can use a factory method to minimize #ifdefs.  And you can use templates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) to further reduce it.

Comment: C++ is so old and poor language ((

Comment: Microsoft's C++/CX supports partial class with non-standard keywords, `partial` and `ref`, just before `class` keyword, and here's its [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/partial-classes-c-cx?view=vs-2019). I'd rather avoid using this feature 'cause it's not standard C++.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is not possible in C++, it will give you an error about redefining already-defined classes. If you'd like to share behavior, consider inheritance.

Answer (score 24):

Try inheritance

Specifically

```
class AllPlatforms {
public:
    int common();
};
```

and then

```
class PlatformA : public AllPlatforms {
public:
    int specific();
};
```

Answer (score 20):

You can't partially define classes in C++.

Here's a way to get the "polymorphism, where there's only one subclass" effect you're after without overhead and with a bare minimum of #define or code duplication. It's called simulated dynamic binding:

```
template <typename T>
class genericTest {
public:
    void genericMethod() {
        // do some generic things
        std::cout << "Could be any platform, I don't know" << std::endl;
        // base class can call a method in the child with static_cast
        (static_cast<T*>(this))->doClassDependentThing();
    }
};

#ifdef _WIN32
    typedef Win32Test Test;
#elif MAC
    typedef MacTest Test;
#endif
```

Then off in some other headers you'll have:

```
class Win32Test : public genericTest<Win32Test> {
public:
    void win32Method() {
        // windows-specific stuff:
        std::cout << "I'm in windows" << std::endl;
        // we can call a method in the base class
        genericMethod();
        // more windows-specific stuff...
    }
    void doClassDependentThing() {
        std::cout << "Yep, definitely in windows" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and

```
class MacTest : public genericTest<MacTest> {
public:
    void macMethod() {
        // mac-specific stuff:
        std::cout << "I'm in MacOS" << std::endl;
        // we can call a method in the base class
        genericMethod();
        // more mac-specific stuff...
    }
    void doClassDependentThing() {
        std::cout << "Yep, definitely in MacOS" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This gives you proper polymorphism at compile time. genericTest can non-virtually call doClassDependentThing in a way that gives it the platform version, (almost like a virtual method), and when win32Method calls genericMethod it of course gets the base class version.

This creates no overhead associated with virtual calls - you get the same performance as if you'd typed out two big classes with no shared code. It may create a non-virtual call overhead at con(de)struction, but if the con(de)structor for genericTest is inlined you should be fine, and that overhead is in any case no worse than having a genericInit method that's called by both platforms.

Client code just creates instances of Test, and can call methods on them which are either in genericTest or in the correct version for the platform. To help with type safety in code which doesn't care about the platform and doesn't want to accidentally make use of platform-specific calls, you could additionally do:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    typedef genericTest<Win32Test> BaseTest;
#elif MAC
    typedef genericTest<MacTest> BaseTest;
#endif
```

You have to be a bit careful using BaseTest, but not much more so than is always the case with base classes in C++. For instance, don't slice it with an ill-judged pass-by-value. And don't instantiate it directly, because if you do and call a method that ends up attempting a "fake virtual" call, you're in trouble. The latter can be enforced by ensuring that all of genericTest's constructors are protected.

Comment: I think you got the same line of thought, I liked it.

Comment: You should be able to find more tips and tricks by searching on "simulated dynamic binding" or maybe "static polymorphism". I'm not sure I've ever seriously used it, since in practice it's quite rare for the overhead of virtual calls to actually matter. If it ever does, though, I'll be ready :-)

Comment: I suggest using our [Polymorph abstraction](https://github.com/linksplatform/Interfaces/blob/master/cpp/Platform.Interfaces/Polymorph.h) for any polymorphism, both static and optionally dynamic.

Answer (score 11):

or you could try PIMPL

common header file:

```
class Test
{
public:
    ...
    void common();
    ...
private:
    class TestImpl;
    TestImpl* m_customImpl;
};
```

Then create the cpp files doing the custom implementations that are platform specific.

Answer (score 10):

```
#include will work as that is preprocessor stuff.

class Foo
{
#include "FooFile_Private.h"
}

////////

FooFile_Private.h:

private:
  void DoSg();
```

Comment: I would recommend a different file extension to prevent accidental importing outside of a class. FooFile_Private.partial

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
class WindowsFuncs { public: int f(); int winf(); };
class MacFuncs { public: int f(); int macf(); }

class Funcs
#ifdef Windows 
    : public WindowsFuncs
#else
    : public MacFuncs
#endif
{
public:
    Funcs();
    int g();
};
```

Now `Funcs` is a class known at compile-time, so no overheads are caused by abstract base classes or whatever.

Comment: What you do here, you can do using templates and static polymorphism. For example, look at our [Polymorph type](https://github.com/linksplatform/Interfaces/blob/master/cpp/Platform.Interfaces/Polymorph.h), that has type parameters for any number of base types to be redefined just before usage of the class.

Answer (score 3):

As written, it is not possible, and in some cases it is actually annoying.

There was an official proposal to the ISO, with in mind embedded software, in particular to avoid the RAM ovehead given by both inheritance and pimpl pattern (both approaches require an additional pointer for each object):

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0309r0.pdf

Unfortunately the proposal was rejected.

Answer (score 2):

As written, it is not possible.

You may want to look into namespaces. You can add a function to a namespace in another file. The problem with a class is that each .cpp needs to see the full layout of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

But, you may want to look up a technique called "Policy Classes".  Basically, you make micro-classes (that aren't useful on their own) then glue them together at some later point.

Comment: Pretty cool! Wikipedia has a nice example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

Answer (score 2):

Either use inheritance, as Jamie said, or #ifdef to make different parts compile on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Since headers are just textually inserted, one of them could omit the "class Test {" and "}" and be #included in the middle of the other.

I've actually seen this in production code, albeit Delphi not C++. It particularly annoyed me because it broke the IDE's code navigation features.

Comment: This is very misguided, very misguided, but a valid solution I think :-)

Answer (score 2):

> For me it seems quite useful for definining multi-platform classes that have common functions between them that are platform-independent.

Except developers have been doing this for decades without this 'feature'.

I believe partial was created because Microsoft has had, for decades also, a bad habit of generating code and handing it off to developers to develop and maintain.

Generated code is often a maintenance  nightmare.  What habits to that entire MFC generated framework when you need to bump your MFC version?  Or how do you port all that code in *.designer.cs files when you upgrade Visual Studio?

Most other platforms rely more heavily on generating **configuration files** instead that the user/developer can modify.  Those, having a more limited vocabulary and not prone to be mixed with unrelated code.  The configuration files can even be inserted in the binary as a resource file if deemed necessary.

I have never seen 'partial' used in a place where inheritance or a configuration resource file wouldn't have done a better job.

Comment: What if you have a template interface class from which you inherit CRTP-fashion, which is also talked to by another template class with the same specializations, and classes derived from the interface and using the pImpl idiom have identical implementations for all public functions, but must have different platform-specific implementations for all private functions?  Partial classes would be cleaner here than including separate Impl files above the public interface implementation based on a #ifdef switch.

Comment: Very late reply, but an emulator with seperates functions for each instruction form would be easier IMO with partial classes. If you put all the declarations in one file (which C++ requires), you’d have _1000s_ of function definitions in _one file!_ For Bochs, look at the end of `cpu/cpu.h`: https://sourceforge.net/p/bochs/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/bochs/cpu/cpu.h . If partial classes were a thing, you could separate those definitions out. While not necessary, it would shrink the file considerably.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty but practical way is using #include preprocessor:

Test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Test
{
public:
    Test(void);
    virtual ~Test(void);

#include "Test_Partial_Win32.h"
#include "Test_Partial_OSX.h"

};

#endif // !TEST_H
```

Test_Partial_OSX.h:

```
// This file should be included in Test.h only.

#ifdef MAC
    public:
        int macMethod();
#endif // MAC
```

Test_Partial_WIN32.h:

```
// This file should be included in Test.h only.

#ifdef _WIN32
    public:
        int win32Method();
#endif // _WIN32
```

Test.cpp:

```
// Implement common member function of class Test in this file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test(void)
{
}

Test::~Test(void)
{
}
```

Test_Partial_OSX.cpp:

```
// Implement OSX platform specific function of class Test in this file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"

#ifdef MAC
int Test::macMethod()
{
    return 0;
}
#endif // MAC
```

Test_Partial_WIN32.cpp:

```
// Implement WIN32 platform specific function of class Test in this file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
int Test::win32Method()
{
    return 0;
}
#endif // _WIN32
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that I have:

MyClass_Part1.hpp, MyClass_Part2.hpp and MyClass_Part3.hpp

**Theoretically** someone can develop a GUI tool that reads all these hpp files above and creates the following hpp file:

MyClass.hpp

```
class MyClass
{
   #include <MyClass_Part1.hpp>
   #include <MyClass_Part2.hpp>
   #include <MyClass_Part3.hpp>
};
```

The user can **theoretically** tell the GUI tool where is each input hpp file and where to create the output hpp file.

Of course that the developer can **theoretically** program the GUI tool to work with any varying number of hpp files (not necessarily 3 only) whose prefix can be any arbitrary string (not necessarily "MyClass" only).

Just don't forget to `#include <MyClass.hpp>` to use the class "MyClass" in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a class body twice will likely generate a type redefinition error.  If you're looking for a work around.  I'd suggest #ifdef'ing, or using an [Abstract Base Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_base_class) to hide platform specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something like partial classes using *template specialization* and *partial specialization*.  Before you invest too much time, check your compiler's support for these.  Older compilers like MSC++ 6.0 didn't support partial specialization.

Answer (score 1):

> This is not possible in C++, it will give you an error about redefining already-defined 
>   classes. If you'd like to share behavior, consider inheritance.

I do agree on this. Partial classes is strange construct that makes it very difficult to maintain afterwards. It is difficult to locate on which partial class each member is declared and redefinition or even reimplementation of features are hard to avoid.

Do you want to extend the std::vector, you have to inherit from it. This is because of several reasons. First of all you change the responsibility of the class and (properly?) its class invariants. Secondly, from a security point of view this should be avoided. 
Consider a class that handles user authentication...

```
partial class UserAuthentication {
  private string user;
  private string password;
  public bool signon(string usr, string pwd);
}

partial class UserAuthentication {
  private string getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

A lot of other reasons could be mentioned...

Comment: They don’t work really in C++ because headers are a thing, but in C#, even if a class is `partial`, you can’t add to it outside the assembly (a compiled project) it is in. And if you want to prevent inheritance (in C#), just make the class `sealed`; Prior to C++11 and `final`, that wasn’t possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let platform independent and platform dependent classes/functions be each-others friend classes/functions. :)

And their separate name identifiers permit finer control over instantiation, so coupling is looser. Partial breaks encapsulation foundation of OO far too absolutely, whereas the requisite friend declarations barely relax it just enough to facilitate multi-paradigm Separation of Concerns like Platform Specific aspects from Domain-Specific platform independent ones.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing something similar in my rendering engine.  I have a templated IResource interface class from which a variety of resources inherit (stripped down for brevity):

```
template <typename TResource, typename TParams, typename TKey>
class IResource
{
public:
    virtual TKey GetKey() const = 0;
protected:
    static shared_ptr<TResource> Create(const TParams& params)
    {
        return ResourceManager::GetInstance().Load(params);
    }
    virtual Status Initialize(const TParams& params, const TKey key, shared_ptr<Viewer> pViewer) = 0;
};
```

The `Create` static function calls back to a templated ResourceManager class that is responsible for loading, unloading, and storing instances of the type of resource it manages with unique keys, ensuring duplicate calls are simply retrieved from the store, rather than reloaded as separate resources.

```
template <typename TResource, typename TParams, typename TKey>
class TResourceManager
{
    sptr<TResource> Load(const TParams& params) { ... }
};
```

Concrete resource classes inherit from IResource utilizing the CRTP.  ResourceManagers specialized to each resource type are declared as friends to those classes, so that the ResourceManager's `Load` function can call the concrete resource's `Initialize` function.  One such resource is a texture class, which further uses a pImpl idiom to hide its privates:

```
class Texture2D : public IResource<Texture2D , Params::Texture2D , Key::Texture2D >
{
    typedef TResourceManager<Texture2D , Params::Texture2D , Key::Texture2D > ResourceManager;
    friend class ResourceManager;

public:
    virtual Key::Texture2D GetKey() const override final;
    void GetWidth() const;
private:
    virtual Status Initialize(const Params::Texture2D & params, const Key::Texture2D key, shared_ptr<Texture2D > pTexture) override final;

    struct Impl;
    unique_ptr<Impl> m;
};
```

Much of the implementation of our texture class is platform-independent (such as the `GetWidth` function if it just returns an int stored in the Impl).  However, depending on what graphics API we're targeting (e.g. Direct3D11 vs. OpenGL 4.3), some of the implementation details may differ.  One solution could be to inherit from IResource an intermediary Texture2D class that defines the extended public interface for all textures, and then inherit a D3DTexture2D and OGLTexture2D class from that.  The first problem with this solution is that it requires users of your API to be constantly mindful of which graphics API they're targeting (they could call `Create` on both child classes).  This could be resolved by restricting the `Create` to the intermediary Texture2D class, which uses maybe a `#ifdef` switch to create either a D3D or an OGL child object.  But then there is still the second problem with this solution, which is that the platform-independent code would be duplicated across both children, causing extra maintenance efforts.  You could attempt to solve this problem by moving the platform-independent code into the intermediary class, but what happens if some of the member data is used by both platform-specific and platform-independent code?  The D3D/OGL children won't be able to access those data members in the intermediary's Impl, so you'd have to move them out of the Impl and into the header, along with any dependencies they carry, exposing anyone who includes your header to all that crap they don't need to know about.

API's should be easy to use right and hard to use wrong.  Part of being easy to use right is restricting the user's exposure to only the parts of the API they should be using.  This solution opens it up to be easily used wrong and adds maintenance overhead.  Users should only have to care about the graphics API they're targeting in one spot, not everywhere they use your API, and they shouldn't be exposed to your internal dependencies.  This situation screams for partial classes, but they are not available in C++.  So instead, you might simply define the Impl structure in separate header files, one for D3D, and one for OGL, and put an `#ifdef` switch at the top of the Texture2D.cpp file, and define the rest of the public interface universally.  This way, the public interface has access to the private data it needs, the only duplicate code is data member declarations (construction can still be done in the Texture2D constructor that creates the Impl), your private dependencies stay private, and users don't have to care about anything except using the limited set of calls in the exposed API surface:

```
// D3DTexture2DImpl.h
#include "Texture2D.h"
struct Texture2D::Impl
{
    /* insert D3D-specific stuff here */
};

// OGLTexture2DImpl.h
#include "Texture2D.h"
struct  Texture2D::Impl
{
    /* insert OGL-specific stuff here */
};

// Texture2D.cpp
#include "Texture2D.h"

#ifdef USING_D3D
#include "D3DTexture2DImpl.h"
#else
#include "OGLTexture2DImpl.h"
#endif

Key::Texture2D Texture2D::GetKey() const
{
    return m->key;
}
// etc...
```